# Disabling ASP .NET CheckBoxList

Tags: asp.net, html, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9, checkboxlist

I'm building a dynamic ASP table, with CheckBoxLists in each cell. Based on internal conditions, some of these lists should be disabled. It works in Chrome and FF, but not in IE9. I've stepped through the code that is doing the disabling, and the Enabled property is correctly set to false, but it doesn't render correctly to IE. Anyone have an idea why?

```
Table optionTBL = new Table();
optionTBL.ID = "optionTBL";
TableRow headerRow = new TableRow();
TableRow listRow = new TableRow();
listRow.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Top;
foreach( string[] iss in issues )
{
    // make a header
    TableHeaderCell cell = new TableHeaderCell();
    string headerTXT = "BLAH";
    cell.Text = headerTXT;
    cell.Width = Unit.Percentage( 33 );
    cell.Height = Unit.Pixel( 1 );
    cell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
    headerRow.Cells.Add( cell );

    // put all the options in the radio list
    CheckBoxList checkLST = new CheckBoxList();
    checkLST.ID = "CKBLST" + iss[ 0 ];
    while( condition )
    {
        // build the issue radios here
        checkLST.Items.Add( new ListItem( "Text", "Value" ) );
    }

    foreach( ListItem li in checkLST.Items )
        li.Attributes.Add( "theValue", li.Value );

    // put the list in a cell in the row in the table
    TableCell cell2 = new TableCell();
    // some formatting
    checkLST.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
    checkLST.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid;
    checkLST.BorderWidth = 1;
    checkLST.Width = Unit.Percentage( 100 );
    // here we disable the check list if needed
    if( needDisabled )
    {
        // disable the list, and check one
        checkLST.Enabled = false;
        checkLST.Items[ alreadySelected ].Selected = true;
    }
    // add the list in the cell
    cell2.Controls.Add( checkLST );
    cell2.Width = Unit.Percentage( 33 );
    // put the cell in the row
    listRow.Cells.Add( cell2 );
}

// put the table in the literal
optionTBL.Height = Unit.Percentage( 100 );
optionTBL.CellPadding = 5;
optionTBL.CssClass = "vote_table";

// here we have all the tables we need, stick em all in the literal on the page
contentPanel.Controls.Add( optionTBL );
```

content panel is in the ASPX as follows, and is the only control in the markup

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="contentPanel" Height="450px" ></asp:Panel>
```

output from IE9

```
<div style="height: 450px;" id="contentPanel">
<table style="height: 100%;" id="optionTBL" class="vote_table" border="0" cellPadding="5">
<tbody><tr>
<th style="width: 33%; height: 1px;" align="center">ballot 1<br>Select 1<br></th><th style="width: 33%; height: 1px;" align="center">ballot 2<br>Select 1<br></th>
</tr><tr vAlign="top">
<td style="width: 33%;"><table style="border: 1px solid black; width: 100%;" id="CKBLST8"" border="0">
<tbody><tr>
<td><span theValue="29"><input id="CKBLST8_0" name="CKBLST8$0" type="checkbox"><label for="CKBLST8_0">Name A</label></span></td>
</tr><tr>
<td><span theValue="30"><input id="CKBLST8_1" name="CKBLST8$1" type="checkbox"><label for="CKBLST8_1">Name B</label></span></td>
</tr><tr>
<td><span theValue="0" WWW="1"><input id="CKBLST8_2" name="CKBLST8$2" type="checkbox"><label for="CKBLST8_2"><input id="writeIn82" value="Write In Candidate" type="text"></label></span></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table></td><td style="width: 33%;"><table style="border: 1px solid black; width: 100%;" id="CKBLST9"" border="0">
<tbody><tr>
<td><span theValue="31"><input id="CKBLST9_0" name="CKBLST9$0" type="checkbox"><label for="CKBLST9_0">Name 1</label></span></td>
</tr><tr>
<td><span theValue="33"><input id="CKBLST9_1" name="CKBLST9$1" type="checkbox"><label for="CKBLST9_1">Name 2</label></span></td>
</tr><tr>
<td><span theValue="0" WWW="1"><input id="CKBLST9_2" name="CKBLST9$2" type="checkbox">   <label for="CKBLST9_2"><input id="writeIn92" value="Write In Candidate" type="text">         </label></span></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</div>
```

output from chrome

```
<div id="contentPanel" style="height:450px;">
<table id="optionTBL" class="vote_table" cellpadding="5" border="0" style="height:100%;">
<tbody><tr>
<th align="center" style="height:1px;width:33%;">ballot 1<br>Select 1<br></th><th align="center" style="height:1px;width:33%;">ballot 2<br>Select 1<br></th>
</tr><tr valign="top">
<td style="width:33%;"><table id="CKBLST8" disabled="disabled" border="0" style="border-color:Black;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;width:100%;">
<tbody><tr>
<td><span disabled="disabled" thevalue="29"><input id="CKBLST8_0" type="checkbox" name="CKBLST8$0" checked="checked" disabled="disabled"><label for="CKBLST8_0">Name A</label></span></td>
</tr><tr>
<td><span disabled="disabled" thevalue="30"><input id="CKBLST8_1" type="checkbox" name="CKBLST8$1" disabled="disabled"><label for="CKBLST8_1">Name B</label></span></td>
</tr><tr>
<td><span disabled="disabled" thevalue="0"><input id="CKBLST8_2" type="checkbox" name="CKBLST8$2" disabled="disabled"><label for="CKBLST8_2"><input type="text" id="writeIn82" value="" disabled="disabled"></label></span></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table></td><td style="width:33%;"><table id="CKBLST9" disabled="disabled" border="0" style="border-color:Black;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;width:100%;">
<tbody><tr>
<td><span disabled="disabled" thevalue="31"><input id="CKBLST9_0" type="checkbox" name="CKBLST9$0" checked="checked" disabled="disabled"><label for="CKBLST9_0">Name 1</label></span></td>
</tr><tr>
<td><span disabled="disabled" thevalue="33"><input id="CKBLST9_1" type="checkbox" name="CKBLST9$1" disabled="disabled"><label for="CKBLST9_1">Name 2</label></span></td>
</tr><tr>
<td><span disabled="disabled" thevalue="0"><input id="CKBLST9_2" type="checkbox" name="CKBLST9$2" disabled="disabled"><label for="CKBLST9_2"><input type="text" id="writeIn92" value="" disabled="disabled"></label></span></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</div>
```

Note this only the portion of the ASP Panel, not the whole webpage

Comment: Can you also show the rendered html in IE9?

Comment: This is somewhat strange. The Chrome html would work in IE9 (or FF) without a problem. So why was it rendered broken for IE? Why is the `disabled="disabled"` omitted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting the attribute enabled=false, set an attribute of disabled=disabled

```
li.Attributes.Add( "disabled", "disabled" );
```

Comment: That worked. I also had to add the checked='checked' attribute. Also of note, this method didn't display correctly in Chrome. So in using both my original code, and this attribute method displays correctly in both. Though I'm still not sure why, it at least is working now. Thanks for the help!